# Calculus 2- Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> Calculate the integral $$\int_1^6 (6f(x)-4) dx$$ assuming that $\int_1^b f(x) dx =1-b^{-1}$.

I thought substituting $6$ in for $b$ would do the trick, but I couldn't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What is the logic behind your assumption?

Comment: May be, you could expand.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{1}^{6}(6f(x)-4)dx=6\int_{1}^{6}f(x)dx-4\int_{1}^{6}dx=6(1-6^{-1})-4(6-1)=5-20=-15$$

Comment: Oh wow, i totally forgot about taking the constants out, Thanks man!